# Parsing command line arguments in a shell script function

Tags: shell

The shell command line parameters list $@ prints nothing. So I have taken args in ALL_ARGS_PASSED and sent them to function. Even then Iam unable to parse the arguments.

Parsing $@ (list of all commandline args)

set them in ALL_ARGS_PASSED and tried to parse in function

```
ALL_PASSED_ARGS="$@"

get_args_rethink()
{
   #echo $ALL_PASSED_ARGS
   echo "All args passed $@"
   for arg in $ALL_PASSED_ARGS
   do
       KEY=$(echo $arg | cut -f1 -d=)
       VALUE=$(echo $arg | cut -f2 -d=)

       case "$KEY" in
           GIT_USERNAME)                     READ_GIT_USERNAME=${VALUE} ;;
           GIT_PASSWORD)                     READ_GIT_PASSWORD=${VALUE} ;;
           *)                                echo "PLEASE SEE USAGE"  ;;
       esac
   done
}

get_args_rethink aa=1 bb=2
echo "$READ_GIT_USERNAME first parameter"
echo "$READ_GIT_PASSWORD second parameter"
```

Expecting ALL_ARGS_PASSED contains all arguments
This need to be successfully parsed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function can have arguments passed. so $@ inside function becomes functions args not the shell arguments at command line.

ALL_ARGS_PASSED="$@" is wrong $@ is already quoted args list. If you quote again it becomes single string and hence only first argument is parsed rest are the value.

""aa=1 bb=2 cc=3""
so if you parse this aa is key and value is "1 bb=2 cc=3"

so the solution is not to quote for ALL_ARGS_PASSED

```
ALL_PASSED_ARGS=$@
```

Comment: Copying `$@` to another variable wrecks any quoting. You want to pass `"$@"` as the argument to the function instead to properly preserve all the arguments with quoting intact.